# Hadoop Yarn container configuration (CPU, Memory...)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I've just setup a new Hadoop cluster with Hadoop 2.2.0 and running the MapReduce job on HBase based on Yarn framework.

I have a problem of the configuration of containers. In general, we have 8 nodes, half of which are old machines with 8 cores CPU and half of which are new machines with 24 cores CPU. I wonder if it's possible to configure separately with more containers in new machines and less in old machines. With actual setting, the number of containers are limited to 8 which means 1 core per container at least. Even though, I have resources left in new machines, it's not allocated to more containers in new machines. We use the fair scheduler.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration file `yarn-site.xml`, there is a property named `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` which defines the CPU cores of the node. As I set this value differently of the old and the new machines, more containers are running in new nodes.

I again answer my own question :)

Comment: Hi, Just found you questions and answer. can you please explain more details about this? because as I see in my cluster this parameter can take only one value. In you case, for my understanding, you need to setup cpu-vcores for old nodes and cpu-vcores for new nodes. thanks

Comment: @GlibMartynenko, Yes, just set this parameter to different value for different nodes. For example for old node of 4 cores, set this to 4; for new nodes of 16 cores, set this to 16.

Comment: thank You for your replay. Hm... we use Ambari to manage all settings and there is no way to set different parameters for different nodes...